# zlib not found when installing ShortRead

Tags: anaconda, zlib

I am using R (3.4.3) installed via anaconda (version 5.2). I have installed zlib using conda already. But when trying to install the Bioconductor R package: "ShortRead" I am getting this error:

```
checking for gzeof in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ShortRead’
```

I tried installing inside R using Bioconductor biocLite and install.packages, but no luck!

I also tried installing directly from conda:

```
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-shortread 
Solving environment: failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - bioconductor-shortread
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

It seems this package is not available for R 3.4.3 from conda.

I also manually downloaded the zlib package. After compiling, I tried installing by exporting my LD library path to zlib''s lib location:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pathtozlib/zlib/lib
```

It didn't help either. Any help would be appreciated!

P.S I don't have root privileges in the machine I am working.

I found other people facing this issue:
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/108808/. They suggest that it could be a problem with conda library.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem lies with the configuration of `autotools` in `r-base>3.4.1b2`, but I'm not competent to fix that.  The plus side is that, although `configure` can't find `zlib` during the pre-installation, `zlib` is actually present in any Conda environment with `r-base` and can be linked during the actual installation.  I filed an [issue at Conda-Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/issues/74), but until and unless the issue is resolved in `r-base`, I made a fork of `ShortRead` which skips the check.  It works for me with `r-base=3.5.1`.

**tldr:** `remotes::install_github("brendanf/ShortRead")`

Comment: I am facing the same problem with zlib. When I run `remotes::install_github("brendanf/ShortRead")` I get `Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = download_method(), quiet = quiet,`. Can you please suggest how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @Hrant Could you post the rest of the error message? It looks like a network problem.  Are you able to successfully install other packages using `remotes::install_github`?

Comment: It was a `remotes` problem, I tried with `devtools`, it loads, but throws another error:
`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ShortRead’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/nfs/users/tg/hhovhannisyan/Software/anaconda2/envs/rstudio3.5/lib/R/library/ShortRead/libs/ShortRead.so':
  /nfs/users/tg/hhovhannisyan/Software/anaconda2/envs/rstudio3.5/lib/R/library/ShortRead/libs/ShortRead.so: undefined symbol: gzeof
Error: loading failed
Execution halted`

Comment: Now it looks like you actually are missing zlib, or it is an incompatible version.  What do you get with `conda list zlib`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It shows that I have `zlib 1.2.11`

Comment: @Hrant I just now tried the following on my system: `conda create -n zlibtest r-base=3.5.1 r-recommended r-remotes`, followed by `conda activate zlibtest`.  Then, in R, `remotes::install_github("brendanf/ShortRead")`.  This was successful.  If that doesn't work for you, then there must be something system specific going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for the past week. I tried every thing that was mentioned regarding the zlib library on the internet. I couldn't fix it properly. I have the zlib installed as when I run: pkg-config zlib --libs; I get as output: -lz
`$ pkg-config zlib --libs
-lz`

I am running conda (v4.5.4). R version 3.4.3 and I have R as a conda environment. I think the problem is with multiple zlib libraries (ubuntu base and conda).

Somehow I just made this to work. What I did was to install R in ubuntu shell (i.e. outside conda) and install the ShortRead library there. There was no conflict/error with the zlib. After that I added the core Rlib directories to libPaths in conda.

`$.libPaths(c('/home/aridaman/.conda/envs/rstudio/lib/R/library','/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/','/usr/lib/R/site-library','/usr/lib/R/site-library'))`

This is not ideal but somehow worked for me. I would be glad to have a better conda based solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a deep learning algorithm where opencv is used and if u get zlib not found while all the dependencies are being installed don't panic. I had the same problem.There can the following reasons:

1. If you've installed a IDE like anaconde your pip version will be automatically set to `3.4.2` and in this version `zlib.h` has a problem so it will show an error.So prefer to create a virtual environment and try installing the latest version of pip and if its not happening uninstall anaconda and use jupyter from pip{having the latest pip version}.
2. If you're pip version is not updated, update it by the latest version.